# Stringizing operator

Tags: c, macros

How does the following code compile correctly,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define stringer( x ) printf_s( #x "\n" )
int main() {
stringer( "In quotes when printed to the screen" );   
}
```

isn't it supposed to get expanded into

```
printf_s(""In quotes when printed to the screen""\n");
```

which is an error as there are nested double quotes in printf_s??

Comment: BTW, in this example it's much better to use `puts` than `printf_s`.  Having a smaller attack surface gives more security than layers of validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `#` operator handles character string literals specially. It must `\` escape each `"` in a character string literal that is passed to it. The correct expansion is:

```
printf_s( "\"In quotes when printed to the screen\"" "\n" );
```

Comment: It escapes character *and* string literals specially. Quotes and backslashes are escaped in either kind of token.

Comment: Modern compilers have integrated preprocessors, so there might not be any point at which the source character sequence `"\"In quotes when printed to the screen\""` exists in memory; instead the `#` operator will produce a string-literal token whose value is `"In quotes when printed to the screen"`, bypassing escape processing.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's expanded into

```
printf_s("\"In quotes when printed to the screen\"" "\n");
```

which will finally be

```
printf_s("\"In quotes when printed to the screen\"\n");
```

and should print

```
"In quotes when printed to the screen"
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, adjacent string literals [are concatenated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation):

> Adjacent string literals are concatenated at compile time; this allows long strings to be split over multiple lines, and also allows string literals resulting from C preprocessor defines and macros to be appended to strings at compile time:

Comment: He seems to be using that on purpose, it's not the question.