# What does #x inside a C macro mean?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

For example I have a macro:

```
#define PRINT(int) printf(#int "%d\n",int)
```

I kinda know what is the result.
But how come #int repersent the whole thing?

I kinda forget this detail. Can anybody kindely give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Possbible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676999/stringizing-operator

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In this context (applied to a parameter reference in a macro definition), the pound sign means to expand this parameter to the literal text of the argument that was passed to the macro.

In this case, if you call `PRINT(5)` the macro expansion will be `printf("5" "%d\n", 5);` which will print `5 5`; not very useful; however if you call `PRINT(5+5)` the macro expansion will be `printf("5+5" "%d\n", 5+5);` which will print `5+5 10`, a little less trivial.

This very example is explained in [this tutorial on the C preprocessor](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html) (which, incidentally, is the first Google hit for [c macro pound sign](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+macro+pound+sign)).

Comment: is this gcc feature or ANSi C standard?

Comment: @AndersLind: This is standard behaviour. See §6.10.3.2/2 which details the semantics of the `#` operator.

Comment: @dreamlax  wow, thanks. I never use it in my 10 years programming life...damn!..tho I program c++ for most time

Comment: Actually `5+510`. Spaces between string tokens are ignored(not converted to space char ` `).

Comment: Now this question is the first Google hit for "c macro pound sign" :)

Comment: Where would the space in the output come from?

Comment: Does this work passing to the macro variables or math operations (e.g. `2*5`)?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi And for the first example `55` would be printed instead of `5 5`

Answer (score 19):

"#" can show the name of a variable, it's better to define the macro as this:

```
#define PRINT(i) printf(#i " = %d\n", i)
```

and use it like this:

```
int i = 5;
PRINT(i);
```

Result shown:

```
i = 5
```

Answer (score 8):

That is a bad choice of name for the macro parameter, but harmless (thanks dreamlax).

Basically if i write like so

```
PRINT(5);
```

It will be replaced as

```
printf("5" "%d\n",5);
```

or

```
printf("5 %d\n",5);
```

It is a process called [Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/cpp/Stringification.html), #int is replaced with a string consisting of its content, 5 -> "5"

Comment: The macro is expanded by the preprocessor which has no knowledge of the C type system. As far as I am aware `int` doesn't break any rules in §6.10 (Preprocessing directives), but I agree it is a bad choice.

Comment: Your link to Stringification documentation is dead, please update.

Comment: @DrewBuckley fixed!

Comment: `"5 %d\n"` wrong `"5%d\n"` right

Answer (score 3):

'#' is called a stringize operator.
Stringize operator puts quotes around the parameter passed and returns a string. It is only used in a marco statements that take the arguments.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

#define stringLiteral(sl) #sl

int main()
{
   char StringizeOpreator = 'a'; 
   printf(stringLiteral(StringizeOpreator));
   return 0;
}
```

Here the `stringLiteral` marco takes the formal argument `sl` and returns `#sl`. Actual argument passed is `StringizeOpreator` variable. The return statement `#sl` has `#` operator, that puts quotes around the argument like `"StringizeOpreator"` and returns a string.

So the output of the above program is the name of the actual parameter 'StringizeOpreator' rather than the value stored in the actual parameter passed.

```
output :
StringizeOperator
...
exitcode 0
```

To learn more visit this link:
[Stringize Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/stringizing-operator-hash?view=vs-2019)