# What it means #value in a macro

Tags: c++, c++11

I found the below macro in an SDK sample program. What #value is meant for in this context?

```
#define VALUE_CHAR(value)       #value, value
```

Comment: What does `#value, value` mean? Does it really a valid statement?

Comment: This ain't new.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351971/what-does-x-inside-a-c-macro-mean/

Comment: http://www.cquestions.com/2009/01/what-is-use-of-and-operator-in-c.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stringification.  See [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) page.

So

```
VALUE_CHAR(1)
```

expands to:

```
"1", 1
```

You might use this kind of macro to simplify initialization of an array, for example:

```
#define MYDEF(x) { #x, x }

static struct {
    const char *str;
    int num;
} values[] = {
    MYDEF(1),
    MYDEF(2),
    MYDEF(3)
};
```

Comment: @trojanfoe: Do we need to have `#value, value`?
Because I tried with `#value` it did work. then why `value` need to be written twice

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak It depends on what that particular macro means to the API/framework you are using.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: In this example, each array initialiser expands to e.g. `{ "1", 1 }`, to initialise both the string and the integer to matching values. With just `#value` it would "work" (in the sense of compiling), but would leave the integer uninitialised.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I am just curious to know how to create object of this structure in ur example above. This is a very good coding. Because I tried with `struct values val;` and `struct values[0] val;` But it is throwing error. Please help me.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Well we are departing from your question, but in my example the struct is *anonymous* (it has no type as such).  If you want to use it elsewhere then `struct myvalue { const char *str; int num; };` and then `static struct myvalue values[] = { ... };`. etc.

Answer (score 3):

From the standard :

> **16.3.2 The # operator [cpp.stringize]**
>
> A *character string literal* is a *string-literal* with no prefix. If, **in the replacement list**, a parameter is immediately **preceded by a `#` preprocessing token**, both are replaced by a single character string literal preprocessing token that contains the spelling of the preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding argument.

It means that:

```
#define VALUE_CHAR(value)    #value, value
VALUE_CHAR(some_value)
```

Will be expanded to :

```
"some_value", some_value
```

by the preprocessor.

---

For example, the famous BOOST Library uses this operator to stringize token :

```
#define BOOST_STRINGIZE(X) BOOST_DO_STRINGIZE(X)
#define BOOST_DO_STRINGIZE(X) #X
```

An example of the usage in the Test library:

```
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( suite_name )                             \
namespace suite_name {                                                  \
  TheFunction( BOOST_STRINGIZE( suite_name ) );                         \
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// ...

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( MyTest );
```

Will be expanded to:

```
namespace MyTest {
    TheFunction( "MyTest" );
//               ^^^^^^^^
```