# Use of # in a macro

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor-directive

**Please explain the code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A(a,b) a##b
#define B(a) #a
#define C(a) B(a)

main()
{
 printf("%s\n",C(A(1,2)));
 printf("%s\n",B(A(1,2)));
}
```

**Output**

> 12
>
> A(1,2)

I don't understand, how the first printf evaluates to 12?
Isn't it similar to the second, as C macro is simply a wrapper to B macro?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351971/what-does-x-inside-a-c-macro-mean/14352054#14352054 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion here comes from a simple rule.

When evaluating a macro the pre-processor first resolves the macros in the arguments passed to the macro. However, as a special case, if an argument is right of `#` or adjacent to `##`, it doesn't resolve macros within such arguments. Such are the rules.

**Your first case**

```
C(A(1,2))
```

The pre-processor first applies the `C(a)` macro, which is defined as `B(a)`. There's no `#` or `##` adjacent to the argument in the definition (none of them in `B(a)` at all), thus the pre-processor must resolve macros in the argument:

```
A(1,2)
```

The definition of `A(a,b)` is `a##b` which evaluates into `12`.

After the macros in the arguments of the `C(a)` macro are evaluated, the C macro becomes:

```
C(12)
```

The pre-processor now resolves the `C(a)` macro, which according to its definition becomes

```
B(12)
```

Once this is done, the pre-processor evaluates macros inside the result once again and applies the `B(a)` macro, so the result becomes

```
"12"
```

**Your second case**

```
B(A(1,2))
```

Similar to the first case, the pre-processor first applies the `B(a)` macro. But this time, the definition of the macro is such that the argument is preceded by `#`. Therefore, the special rule applies and macros inside the argument are **not** evaluated. Therefore, the result immediately becomes:

```
"A(1,2)"
```

The preprocessor goes over the result again trying to find more macros to expand, but now everything is a part of the string, and macros don't get expanded within strings. So the final result is:

```
"A(1,2)"
```

Comment: Thanks @PineForestRanch, I now understood it.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in Wikipedia in [C-preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) :

> The ## operator (known as the "Token Pasting Operator") concatenates
>   two tokens into one token.
>
> The # operator (known as the "Stringification Operator") converts a
>   token into a string, escaping any quotes or backslashes appropriately.
>
> **If you want to stringify the expansion of a macro argument, you have
>   to use two levels of macros:**
>
> You cannot combine a macro argument with additional text and stringify
>   it all together. You can however write a series of adjacent string
>   constants and stringified arguments: the C compiler will then combine
>   all the adjacent string constants into one long string.

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define foo 4

str (foo)  // outputs "foo"
xstr (foo) // outputs "4"
```

Also, [from C-FAQ Question 11.17](http://c-faq.com/ansi/stringize.html) :

> It turns out that the definition of # says that it's supposed to
>   stringize a macro argument immediately, without further expanding it
>   (if the argument happens to be the name of another macro).

So, similarly, going along these lines :

```
you're doing C(A(1,2)), 
which would roll to C(12), // since no #, so inner argument is expanded
and then to B(12)
// [since you've done two levels of macros in the code:
// 1. from C() to B(), and then, 2. B() to #a]
= 12 .
```

Whereas, in the first case, only 1 level of stringification is plainly done as per definition of B(a)(since it gets stringified immediately because of #)

```
macro-replacement of B(A(1,2)) 
= stringification of A(1,2) 
= A(1,2).
```

Comment: Thanks @Am_I_Helpful indeed your helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

C preprocessor has two operators # and ##. The # operator turns the argument of a function like macro to a quoted string where ## operator concatenates two identifiers.

```
#define A(a,b) a##b will concatenate a with b returning ab as string.
so A(1,2) will return 12
#define B(a) #a  will return a as string
#define C(a) B(a) will call previous one and return a as string.
so C(A(1,2)) = C(12) = B(12) = 12 (as string)
B(A(1,2)) = A(1,2) because A(1,2) is taken as an argument and returned as string A(1,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two operators used in the function-like macros:

- `##` causes a macro to concatenate two parameters.
- `#` causes the input to be effectively turned into a string literal.

In `A(a,b)` `##` causes a to be concatenated with b. In `B(a)`, `#` effectively creates a string literal from the input. So the expansion runs as follows:

```
C(A(1,2)) -> C(12) -> B(12) -> "12"
B(A(1,2)) -> "A(1,2)"
```

Because for `C(A(1,2))`, the `A(1,2)` part is evaluated first to turn into 12, the two statements aren't equal like they would appear to be.

You can read more about these at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @js441