# Assign an array or an integer without knowing its nature in the function code (but compiler knows)

Tags: c, arrays, macros, compile-time

I'm looking for something like this snippet.
I expect it to know, at compile time, wether it is dealing with an array or not, and avoid the following errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define IS_ARRAY(x,type) _Generic((&x),          \
                                 type (*)[]: 1,  \
                                 default:   0)

#define GENERIC_ASSIGN(arg,type) if(IS_ARRAY(arg,type)){arg[0] = 1; arg[1] = 2;}else{arg = 2;}

int main(void)
{

    int foo = 0;
    int bar[10] = {0};

    GENERIC_ASSIGN(bar,int); //-->  error: assignment to expression with array type
    GENERIC_ASSIGN(foo,int); //--> error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector  "arg[0] = 1; arg[1] = 2;"

    return 0;
}
```

When I do write GENERIC_ASSIGN(bar,int) i do know that 'bar' is an ARRAY, so does the compiler.

See this topic that explains one part of the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636573/how-can-i-avoid-the-use-of-if-in-a-polymorphic-print-macro)

The problem would have been solved easily if '#if' were allowed inside macros

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic) helps? It shows how to create IF_ELSE macros.

Comment: nope, it's not helping ```IF_ELSE(IS_ARRAY(bar,int))(printf("is_array"))(printf("is_not_array"));``` >> ```error: expected expression before ‘int’;``` IS_ARRAY is expanded after IF_ELSE, so it expands to _IF_IS_ARRAY, but I need _IF_1 or _IF_0.... But interresting article anyway

Comment: Note: I'd use `()` around `x` : `_Generic((&(x)), type (*)[]: 1,  default:   0)`

Comment: Detail: "Assign an array ..." in not possible in C.   Code can _initialize_ an array, but not _assign_ it even though `int bar[10] = {0};` looks like an assignment.  Assignment `bar = {0};` or `bar = (char [10]){0};` not possible.  So, Guillaume D, is your goal to assign an array (somehow) or initialize it or something else?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Not many expressions result in an lvalue so it's not really that important, unless you plan assignment expressions to the macro... which isn't possible in case of arrays.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I want to change the value for one, or more of its fields : (pseudo-code)```arg[0] = 1; arg[1] = 2;``` or ``` for(i=0;i<max;i++){arg[i] = stdin}``` or ```memcpy(arg,another_array,size)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to arrays, so you will have to use memcpy. For example, have the macro create a compound literal of all initializers and then memcpy that one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define IS_ARRAY(x,type) _Generic((&x),                             \
                                 type (*)[]: 1,                     \
                                 default:    0)

#define INIT(arg, type, ...) memcpy(&(arg),                         \
                                    (type[]){__VA_ARGS__},          \
                                    sizeof((type[]){__VA_ARGS__})) 

#define GENERIC_ASSIGN(arg,type) IS_ARRAY(arg,type) ?               \
                                 INIT(arg,type,1,2) :               \
                                 INIT(arg,type,2)

int main(void)
{
  int foo = 0;
  int bar[10] = {0};

  GENERIC_ASSIGN(bar,int);
  GENERIC_ASSIGN(foo,int);

  printf("%d %d\n",bar[0], bar[1]);
  printf("%d\n",foo);

  return 0;
}
```

Notably, with this method it doesn't really matter what type you use, array or not. The size of the initializer list is all that matters.

gcc -O2 resolves this into a couple of register loads (x86):

```
    mov     edx, 2
    mov     esi, 1
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    printf
    mov     esi, 2
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
```

Comment: thank you @Lundin for answering all of my questions :D