# Convert char to int in c

Tags: c

Just trying to print the square of a number using macros.
Self explanatory C program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  numb(a)  \
   printf(#a * #a)

int main(void) {
   int num;
   printf("Enter a num: ");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   numb(num);
   return 0;
}
```

Getting the error :

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:14: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)
    printf(#a * #a)
              ^
main.c:10:14:
    square(num);
              ~
main.c:10:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘square’
    square(num);
    ^~~~~~
```

How can I convert that char to int to sucessfully use the binary operator?

Comment: You’re going to have to end up at `printf("%d", num * num)` somehow, macros or not. Understand that macros operate on bits of C source code at compile time, so `#a` is `"num"`.

Comment: It's not possible to stringize the result of arithmetic, via the preprocessor. You may find the compiler optimizes it though, e.g. it could convert `printf("%d", 5*5);` to `printf("25");`

Comment: `square(1+2)` returns on my machine `5` while I would expect `9`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does #x inside a C macro mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351971/what-does-x-inside-a-c-macro-mean)

Comment: \@Maccen your macro was named `numb` but in the error message it's `square`? @tilz0R if you renamed `numb` to `square` then you'll get `printf("1+2" * "1+2")` in this case

Comment: I would suggest better to use the function to do such kind of things. If you're just learning how to use the function like macro() is fine. Imagine in production code if someone sends in the `num` as `num++` then it's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your macro needs to be c code so just ditch the # and write the formatting string for an integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  square(a)  \
   printf("%d", (a) * (a))

int main(void) {
   int num;
   printf("Enter a num: ");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   square(num);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to say that this is bad macro. a will be evaluated twice. Don't actually use it in real project

Comment: `square(1+2)` returns on my machine `5` while I would expect `9`. Please update answer and warn user.

Comment: added the parenthesis. Nice spotting

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Comment: @texasbruce In a real project you would use a function. But the OP requested a macro, so this does answer the question, good practice or not.

Answer (score -1):

check the output of preprocessor stage by using "cc -E main.c -o main.i" and check how the preprocessor converting macros to instruction .